# Power BI DataSource.Error we were unable to retrieve the contents of the webpage

Tags: powerbi

Not sure if this is the right exchange to post on, but I receive this strange error with Power BI when trying to connect to a web source: E.g. https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/golf/leaderboard

[image]

Doing this in excel the data loads fine.

What's particularly weird, though, is that if I open a previous report, the Web connector still loads correctly; however, if I open the query and click on the Extracted table from Html. I get:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that PowerBI is downloaded via a company portal. Perhaps this is corrupted? Strange though, cause randomly, it will work again and then not.

Furthermore, the HTML will be displayed if I connect to the page as a Text file. So it's not as if the actual connector is the issue, but rather that PowerBI seems unable to preview a webpage (Frustrating, though, as I need to be able to add a table using examples).

Let me know if anyone has any thoughts on things to test out.

Also, I figured it was worth posting this as there doesn't appear to be much information online regarding this. Hopefully, this will be useful to others in the future Some appear to solve it with permissions, but I think my issue is more fundamental.

Comment: Same issue here. Looks like Power BI can't analyse the page structure.

Comment: How odd. My issue seems to be whatever URL I put in I get this error, so I don't think it is the page.

Comment: You could try copying the query over from Excel because it's using a different method to get the contents.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however unfortunately i need the Tables From examples which only can be achieved using Power BI as it has the html.Table function. Amazing that Microsoft doesn't update excel to have this

Comment: What I can do Is work around table from examples by extratcing text from the raw Html. Big faff though

Comment: Just tested out on personal PC and works fine. Potentially some issue with Microsofts WebView2?

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the application was being blocked by my computers security.